# Scroll on a div instead of the whole page when using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to scroll on the `content` div instead of the whole page, how can I do that?

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div style="margin-right: 50px">Sidebar</div>
    <div>
      <div>Header</div>
      <div id="content" style="overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
        laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Searene This is the answer you were looking for with flexbox.
There's two snippets: One, with all the content scrolling and the other with the header being fixed in place.

This is very simple and clean. No fixed widths or css hacks.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;border: solid 10px">
    <div style="margin-right: 50px; background:red">Sidebar</div>
    <div style="background:blue; overflow-x:auto;">
      <div>Header</div>
      <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
        laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this snippet the HEADER stays in place and only the content scrolls.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;border: solid 10px">
    <div style="margin-right: 50px; background:red">Sidebar</div>
    <div style="background:blue; overflow:hidden">
      <div>Header stays in place</div>
      <div id="content" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow:auto">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
        laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, that's really what I want, I looked through your code and found out that the essential difference between your code and mine was that you added an `overflow: hidden`, but I couldn't figure out why it worked after adding it. Could you explain for a little bit?

Comment: It works because you need a container to wrap around your content to constrain/hide content. The block elements afterwards, default to 100% width. From there it was just adding overflow auto/scroll.

Answer (score -1):

I finally gave up `flex` and used `float` to resolve this problem.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
<div style="margin-right: 50px; width: 50px; float: left">Sidebar</div>
<div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 100px)">
  <div>Header</div>
  <div id="content" style="overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
    laborum.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I gave you the answer above. It's about how you "contain" ;)